# give default value to md-autocomplete

Tags: angular-material

How to pass default value in md-autocomplete?

Image 1 : HTML code
Image 2 : JS code
Image 3 : Output

As you can see, I am not getting any default country as output. Is there any way to do that?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used timeout to do this.

```
$timeout(function() {
        $scope.local = {selectedItem : 1}
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign yr SearchText the default value & selectedItem the object.

```
$scope.local ={
     ...
     searchText : 'Default Value',
     selectedItem : 'Default object'
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I write small [codepen](http://codepen.io/dunmaksim/full/xwZBJz/) with autocomplete and default value.
What you must do:

1. Init main model.
2. Define model field, used in autocomplete md-selected-item property.
3. Define callback for loading autocomplete items.
4. Before save main model extract id (or other field) from associated field.

Main error in your code here:

```
$scope.local = {
    ...
    selectedItem: 1, // Must be object, but not integer
    ...
}
```

```js
(function(A) {
  "use strict";

  var app = A.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

  function main(
    $q,
    $scope,
    $timeout
  ) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.user = {
        firstname: "Maxim",
        lastname: "Dunaevsky",
        group: {
          id: 1,
          title: "Administrator"
        }
      };
    }, 500);

    $scope.loadGroups = function(filterText) {
      var d = $q.defer(),
        allItems = [{
          id: 1,
          title: 'Administrator'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Manager'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Moderator'
        }, {
          id: 4,
          title: 'VIP-User'
        }, {
          id: 5,
          title: 'Standard user'
        }];

      $timeout(function() {
        var items = [];

        A.forEach(allItems, function(item) {
          if (item.title.indexOf(filterText) > -1) {
            items.push(item);
          }
        });

        d.resolve(items);
      }, 1000);

      return d.promise;
    };
  }

  main.$inject = [
    '$q',
    '$scope',
    '$timeout'
  ];

  app.controller('Main', main);
}(this.angular));
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="app" flex layout="column" layout-margin ng-controller="Main">
  <md-content layout="column" class="md-whiteframe-z1" layout-margin>
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h3>Form</h3>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content class="md-whiteframe-z1">
      <div class="md-padding">
        <md-input-container>
          <label for="firstname">First name</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" />
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" />
        </md-input-container>
        <md-autocomplete md-selected-item="user.group" md-items="item in loadGroups(filterText)" md-item-text="item.title" md-search-text="filterText">
          <md-item-template>{{ item.title }}</md-item-template>
          <md-not-found>No items.</md-not-found>
        </md-autocomplete>
      </div>
    </md-content>
  </md-content>
  <md-content class="md-whiteframe-z1" layout-margin>
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h3>Model as JSON</h3>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content class="md-padding">
      <p>
        {{ user | json }}
      </p>
    </md-content>
  </md-content>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but some people may benefit from my solution. I struggled with the problem of the model for the auto-complete being asynchronous and having my autocompletes as part of an ng-repeat. Many of the solutions to this problem found on the web have only a single auto complete and static data.

My solution was to add another directive to the autocomplete with a watch on the variable that I want to set as default for the auto complete.

in my template:

```
<md-autocomplete initscope='{{quote["Scope"+i]}}' ng-repeat='i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]'

                    class='m-1'  
                    md-selected-item="ScopeSelected" 
                    md-clear-button="true"
                    md-dropdown-position="top" 
                    md-search-text="pScopeSearch" 
                    md-selected-item-change='selectPScope(item.label,i)'
                    md-items="item in scopePSearch(pScopeSearch,i)"
                    md-item-text="item.label"  
                    placeholder="Plowing Scope {{i}}"                      
                    md-min-length="3"                      
                    md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template"

            >
```

then in my module:

```
Details.directive('initscope', function () {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.$watch(function (){
        return attrs.initscope;
    }, function (value, oldValue) {
        //console.log(attrs.initscope)
        if(oldValue=="" && value!="" && !scope.initialized){
        //console.log(attrs.initscope);
            var item = {id:0, order:0,label:attrs.initscope?attrs.initscope:"" }
            scope.ScopeSelected = item;
            scope.initialized = true;
        }
    });


};
```

});

this checks for changes to the quote["Scope"+i] (because initially it would be null) and creates an initial selected item and sets the autocompletes' selected item to that object. Then it sets an initialized value to true so that this never happens again.